# Custom UIPickerView iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How could i do picker which have as a first column frizzed "`name`" and for second it would have "`data`" ? 
As far as I got it is a picker with 2 components which is  : `name` and `stuff from the list` but it multiple `name` which should be just one and stunned without able to move it and just chaning the data from the list. 
It is able to somewhow implement it ?

That is my custom `UIPickerView` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace Test
{
    class CustomPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        private readonly IList<string> values;
        string name;
        public event EventHandler<PickerChangedEventArgs> PickerChanged;

        public VehiclePickerModel(IList<string> values, string name)
        {
            this.values = values;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView picker)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            return values.Count;
        }

        public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            switch (component)
            {
                case 0:
                    return name;
                case 1:
                    return values[(int)row];
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
        {
            return 40f;
        }

        public override void Selected(UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
        {
            if (this.PickerChanged != null)
            {
                this.PickerChanged(this, new PickerChangedEventArgs { SelectedValue = values[(int)row] });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the visualization what I would like to get :

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to have `NAME:` in a fixed position to the left of your picker data?

Comment: Yeah, Like it would be inside of the picker and only able to move for second component : these letters A-I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are specifying the same number of rows for both components. You need to make sure that you get component `0` to 1 row.

```
public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView picker, nint component)
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
            return 1;
        case 1:
            return values.Count;
        default:
            // However you want to handle
    }
}
```